# C++ MySQL connector link error

Tags: c++, mysql, linker

I'm try to use this example

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

I'm download c++ connector, put dll here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib`

and headers to include folder.

Then I download `boost`, go to Project Properties, C/C++, General, and add it to Additional Include Directories.

I have create c++ console aplication and try run project, but i have error:

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/148/54826950.jpg

Please, tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should change your MySQL root password

Answer (score 0):

There is a linker problem. Check if you had included `MySQL connector`'s library *.DLL into your project's build (link) settings. Or the linker can't find where the external function was implemented. Only include header files is not enough.

P.S: Using empty root password is a bad desicion.

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to missing mysqlcppconn.lib in Project Properties->Linker->Input
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html
Detailed walkthru on how to use mysqlcppconn in your project.

Comment: What is mysqlcppconn.lib?
In connector, that i was download(zip), this file is absent
On official site nothing tell about this file.
Where i can download it? And why this file is absent?

Comment: Where have you downladed zip from? [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) you can download zip archiwe with mysqlcppconn.lib in /lib . Also [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html) you can find detailed instruction how to use it.